# Spring integration : int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter : How to check if the source folder is empty

Tags: spring-integration

I use the int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter to download files from remote directory.

I would like to check if the remote directory is empty , so after a timeout, i stop download and shutdown application.

So how to check that remote directory is empty and how to use a timeout?

my source code:

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
auto-startup="true" channel="receiveChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
local-directory="file:${directory.files.local}" remote-directory="${directory.files.remote}"
auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="true"
filename-pattern="*.txt" >
<int:poller
max-messages-per-poll="-1" error-channel="sftp.in.error.channel"/>

</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no indication when the remote folder is empty.

You might find it easier to use the outbound gateway instead.

You can configure one to use the `ls` command to list the files, and another to `get` (or `mget`) the files.

Comment: Can i use  outbound gateway with command "ls" to check if the directory is empty and then i download files with sftp inbound adapter ?

Comment: Each gateway handles a single command [see the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway). Yes, set `auto-startup` to false and based on the contents of the directory you can `start()` the adapter, using a control bus or getting a reference to it directly.